# Multisite install on subdomain w/ subdomains change siteURL

Tags: multisite

I have a multisite installed on a subdomain and I am trying to make the process of duplicating sites more straight forward. Currently when it is duplicated you must delve into the settings to manually change the siteURL for that particular site from `xxx.xxx.example.com` to `xxx.example.com`.

Is there a way this can be done hooking into `wpmu_create_blog` at all?

If it helps I am currently using NS Cloner Pro to duplicate sites, but I don't think it should matter.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand how multisite is installed. Is it installed as a subdomain platform or is it installed on subdomain?

If it is installed on subdomain then subdomain based multisite will not work (as far I know).
If you want to make automatic subdomains creation you will have to install wordpress into /html_public folder, and you will have to add wildcard domain (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record).

To add wildcard domain go to your cPanel (or whatever you use), navigate to subdomains and add this character as subdomain: *

So... this should be the record: *.your-domain.com